Does a bounded mapping $ T : X \rightarrow Y $ give a bounded mapping $ T : X \otimes Z \rightarrow Y \otimes Z$ with the same norm?
Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are Banach spaces with $Z \neq 0$.
Let $T : X \rightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator.
Does this mapping induce a bounded linear operator $T : X \otimes Z \rightarrow Y \otimes Z$ with the same norm?

Technically, $T : X \otimes Z \rightarrow Y \otimes Z$ is to be understood as the tensor product of $T : X \rightarrow Y$ and $Id : Z \rightarrow Z$.
I don't know which tensor product of Banach spaces (injective, projective, other) I'd rather use here. In my application, $Z$ is actually finite-dimensional.


I have added the assumption $Z \neq 0$ since this is clearly necessary to hope for anything.

Remark: In consideration of Martin’s comment, I should note that I’m assuming $Z \neq 0$ throughout, as otherwise the entire question has a trivially false answer.
The answer is yes when the tensor product is projective. Indeed,
$$\begin{split}
\|(T \otimes \text{Id})(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes z_i)\|_\pi &= \|\sum_{i=1}^n Tx_i \otimes z_i\|_\pi\\
&\leq \|T\| (\sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|\|z_i\|)
\end{split}$$
Taking infimum over all possible ways of writing $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes z_i$ as a finite sum of simple tensors yields,
$$\|(T \otimes \text{Id})(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes z_i)\|_\pi \leq \|T\|\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes z_i\|_\pi$$
So $\|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{\pi \to \pi} \leq \|T\|$. For the converse, pick any unit vector $z \in Z$, then,
$$\begin{split}
\|Tx\| &= \|Tx \otimes z\|_\pi\\
&= \|(T \otimes \text{Id})(x \otimes z)\|_\pi\\
&\leq \|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{\pi \to \pi}\|x \otimes z\|_\pi\\
&= \|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{\pi \to \pi}\|x\|
\end{split}$$
So $\|T\| \leq \|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{\pi \to \pi}$.

Replying to psl2Z’s comment: the same works for the injective tensor norm. Indeed, for any $x \in X \otimes Z$,
$$\begin{split}
\|(T \otimes \text{Id})(x)\|_\epsilon &= \sup_{y’ \in Y^\ast, \|y’\| \leq 1, z’ \in Z^\ast, \|z’\| \leq 1} |(y’ \otimes z’)(T \otimes \text{Id})(x)|\\
&= \sup_{y’ \in Y^\ast, \|y’\| \leq 1, z’ \in Z^\ast, \|z’\| \leq 1} |[(y’ \circ T) \otimes z’](x)|\\
&\leq \sup_{x’ \in X^\ast, \|x’\| \leq \|T\|, z’ \in Z^\ast, \|z’\| \leq 1} |(x’ \otimes z’)(x)|\\
&= \|T\|\|x\|_\epsilon
\end{split}$$
So $\|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{\epsilon \to \epsilon} \leq \|T\|$. The proof of the converse is exactly the same as in the case for the projective tensor norm.
Remark: By altering the proof slightly, it is easy to see that a more general statement holds: namely, for any $T: X \to Y$, $S: Z \to W$, we have,
$$\|T \otimes S\|_{\pi \to \pi} = \|T \otimes S\|_{\epsilon \to \epsilon} = \|T\|\|S\|$$

The result is not true for arbitrary tensor norms, even when $Z$ is finite-dimensional. Indeed, consider $X = Y = Z = M_2(\mathbb{C})$ equipped with the spectral norm. If we equip $X \otimes Z = Y \otimes Z = M_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$ with the unique $C^\ast$-tensor norm (i.e., the norm induced by the spectral norm on $M_4(\mathbb{C})$, via the natural isomorphism $M_2(\mathbb{C}) \otimes M_2(\mathbb{C}) \simeq M_4(\mathbb{C})$), and let $T: X \to Y$ be the transpose map, then $\|T\| = 1$, but,
$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix} e_{11} & e_{21} \\ e_{12} & e_{22} \end{pmatrix}\right\|_{C^\ast} = 1$$
$$\left\|(T \otimes \text{Id})\begin{pmatrix} e_{11} & e_{21} \\ e_{12} & e_{22} \end{pmatrix}\right\|_{C^\ast} = \left\|\begin{pmatrix} e_{11} & e_{12} \\ e_{21} & e_{22} \end{pmatrix}\right\|_{C^\ast} = 2$$
So $\|T \otimes \text{Id}\|_{C^\ast \to C^\ast} \geq 2$.
Remark: When $Z$ is finite-dimensional, all tensor norms are equivalent, so at least $T \otimes \text{Id}$ is always bounded, even if it can have a norm different than that of $T$. When $Z$ is infinite-dimensional, it can happen that for some tensor norms, $T \otimes \text{Id}$ is unbounded altogether. Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ are operator spaces, $Z = K(\ell^2)$, and the tensor norms are spatial tensor norms of operator spaces, then $T \otimes \text{Id}$ is bounded iff $T$ is completely bounded, and there are plenty of examples of bounded but not completely bounded maps.

It seems that it does also hold for the injective tensor product by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443305/duality-of-projective-and-injective-tensor-product and $||T\otimes S||\varepsilon = ||(T\otimes S)'|| = || T' \otimes S' ||\pi = ||T'|| ||S'|| = ||T||||S||$?

@psl2Z It does, though the linked answer only shows this when $S: Z \to W$ has both domain and codomain being finite-dimensional. I’ve added a direct proof of the general fact, without restricting to finite-dimensional spaces, to my answer.

I suppose that $M_k$ are the $k \times k$ matrices?

@AlpinistKitten That is what I meant, yes.
